# Design of experiments. Parameter measurement not continuous

Tags: anova, experiment-design, qualitative

I'd like to do a design of experiments which involves 4 factors, I haven't decided which design yet, prolly, Taguchi or fractioned factorial one.

I used to work with measurable effect but in this case cannot be measured directly. I'm working in a formulation of a paste and the measured effect is compression. We r not able to measure it so we must work with qualitative measures like: low, medium and high compression.

I think I cannot do an ANOVA test like this so I don't know how to check how the factor levels affect compression.  Should I forget about ANOVA and just plan experiments according to a design?

Comment: Design of experiences---do you mean design of experiments?

Comment: yes, I mean experiments

Comment: The key thing here is that the response, conditional on the factors, can hardly be considered normal, even if you were to assign numerical values to high, medium, & low compression. Consider [ordered](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordered-logit) or [multinomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multinomial-logit) logit models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start out planning the experiment in the same way I had done ("as if") the response variable was continuous (the basic principles of experimental design, replication, orthogonality, blocking, ... is the same for continuous and ordinal response variables).  But then doing the analysis using an ordinal logistic model.  Then the analysis of variance is replaced by "analysis of deviance".  Maybe doing some simulation to check upon sample size, in the simulation you must use the ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: But sample size in the experiment should be determined by the experiences contained in exp design. Or do u mean independent replicates of that experiences?

Comment: Yes, that was why I recommended simulation. The simulation is for helping decide sample size---number of replicas of the basic layout